# I cannot use the document injection with angular universal

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular-universal, angular11

I try to use the document property of the DOM to remove and add classes to the html and manage some CSS properties, but when I execute the `ng run app:serve-ssr` command I get the following problem:

[image: Error]

This is my code, it is a service that is in a provider called app-initializer, this is the provider and this is how it is importing in the AppModule.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ThemeService {
 constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

 private loadCss(href: string, id: string): Promise<Event> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const style = this.document.createElement('link');
      style.rel = 'stylesheet';
      style.href = href;
      style.id = id;
      style.onload = resolve;
      style.onerror = reject;
      this.document.head.append(style);
    });
  }
}
```

> AppInitializerProvider

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './utils/services';

export const AppInitializerProvider = {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (themeService: ThemeService) => () => {
    return themeService.loadTheme();
  },
  deps: [ThemeService],
  multi: true,
};
```

> App module

```
// ....
providers: [AppInitializerProvider]
// ....
```

**App version:**

1. Angular CLI: 11.2.7
2. Node: 14.16.0
3. Angular: 11.2.8
4. Test in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge

Comment: `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document` For some reason (don't ask me) `document` should be of type `any`, so `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `appendChild` instead, `append` might not be supported on server side DOM

```
this.document.head.appendChild(style);
```

You could also use `Renderer2`, which is recommanded when manipulating DOM elements from angular

```
this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, style);
```